# angular ngChecked based on service data

Tags: angularjs

I have a input checkbox that i want to be powered by a service's property. When i do

`<input type="checkbox" ng-checked="$ctrl.state.box1.checked" ng-click="$ctrl.handleCheck()">`

and the state is

```
{
    box1: {
        checked: false
    }
}
```

$ctrl.state is provided from Service.state object

handleCheck is something like:

```
function() {
    Service.changeBox1Value()
}
```

Service.changeBox1Value would be something like:

```
function changeBox1Value() {
    // this actually has more complex logic and not just doing toggling
    this.state.box1.checked = !this.state.box1.checked;
}
```

somehow ng-checked does not respect state.box1.checked value.

say i change my `changeBox1Value` to be:

```
function changeBox1Value() {
    this.state.box1.checked = false;
}
```

Every time I click on the checkbox, it still toggles the same way it would by default. I'm expecting, since i explicitly set it to false, for the checkbox to always remain unchecked.

It works if im using ng-model/ng-change but i dont want the view to mutate state directly

How can I make the input to be entirely dependent on the Service state property?

Comment: Please include code of service `Service.changeBox1Value()`

Comment: Is that input or checkbox? Please mention `type="checkbox"` and explain the problem clearly

Comment: i added more info. thanks for looking.

Comment: Is this just an issue with binding to primitives? if so how should i do it so it would respect that bool value?